# How to use jdbctemplate and row mapper to create object with a list of objects?

Tags: java, object, jdbctemplate, dto

I was wondering how to use jdbctemplate and RowMapper to create object with a list of objects?
Below are the three objects that I need to get mapped based on data from the db.

```
public class UserDTO {

private String userID;
private String email;
private List<RooftopDTO> rooftops;

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}
public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public List<RooftopDTO> getRooftops() {
    return rooftops;
}
public void setRooftops(List<RooftopDTO> rooftops) {
    this.rooftops = rooftops;
}

}

public class RooftopDTO {

private String dealerID;
private String name;
private String address;
private List<VenueDTO> venues;

public String getDealerID() {
    return dealerID;
}
public void setDealerID(String dealerID) {
    this.dealerID = dealerID;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public List<VenueDTO> getVenues() {
    return venues;
}
public void setVenues(List<VenueDTO> venues) {
    this.venues = venues;
}

}

public class VenueDTO {

private int integrationID;
private String rooftopID;

public int getIntegrationID() {
    return integrationID;
}
public void setIntegrationID(int integrationID) {
    this.integrationID = integrationID;
}
public String getRooftopID() {
    return rooftopID;
}
public void setRooftopID(String rooftopID) {
    this.rooftopID = rooftopID;
}

}
```

As you can see, I need to create lists of objects within each object. This is what I have so far in my MapperClass, but I can't figure out what else to do..

```
public class UserDTOMapper implements RowMapper<UserDTO> {

@Override
public UserDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
    RooftopDTO rooftops = new RooftopDTO();
    VenueDTO venues = new VenueDTO();
    ArrayList<VenueDTO> venueList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<RooftopDTO> rooftopList = new ArrayList<>();
    userDTO.setUserID(rs.getString("user_id"));
    userDTO.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
    rooftops.setDealerID(rs.getString("dealer_id"));
    rooftops.setAddress(rs.getString("addr_1"));
    rooftops.setName(rs.getString("dealer_nm"));
    venues.setIntegrationID(rs.getInt("integration_id"));
    venues.setRooftopID("act_org_id");
  }
 }
```

Can someone help me finish this mapRow method?

Comment: Assuming the query results in a cartesian join between 3 tables, it's going to be impossible without making the `RowMapper` stateful.  A `ResultSetExtractor` would probably be easier and also to keep it stateless.

Comment: It really depends on how the result set looks like. Show us a sample of the fetched data.